# Can I purposely slow a PC down?

Tags: cpu-speed

I am testing a (non-online) game and I cannot react quickly enough to test the higher levels (I am 60 years old and not as quick as I once was...). Is there any way I can slow the CPU to 50% or even 75%?

Comment: @john this is objectively wrong.  Adaptive speed control can be handled by the OS (as per the link in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to do this depending on your exact goal, however they likely will not actually help you unless the CPU is the bottleneck.   (The easiest way would be to cap the CPU clock speed.  I don't believe you want to do this, but https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95574-change-maximum-processor-frequency-windows-10-a.html talks about how you can do it in Windows 10 - ie by changing maximum processor frequency in Power Options)

Generally, games don't run faster as a computer speeds up, they may, however become less laggy or use excess CPU to provide more detailed imagery.   There is, however something of an edge case - if you are using an emulator to play a classic game, the emulator may be able slow the game down - but we would need to know what emulator you are using!

You should edit the question and include the game in question, and also the OS you are using.

Comment: You may be able to use CheatEngine (https://www.cheatengine.org/) to slow down your games - but I expect the how will depend on the game...